# Save the array labels in a new array

Tags: python, labeling, numpy, array, save

I have several arrays obtained from K means, each array contains a variable number of classes, e.g. from -1 to 3, from 0 to 4, from -1 to n. I would like to be able to save each class of an array as a mask in a new array with the same shape as the original one. Bearing in mind that the number of classes for each array is variable and saving only classes other than -1.

```
with rasterio.open(cluster[0])as ds:
    arr=ds.read()
arr
array([[[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
         -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.],
        [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
          1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1., -1.],
        [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
          2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  1., -1.],
        [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2., -1., -1.]]], dtype=float32)

class = np.unique(arr)
array([-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.], dtype=float32)

#Saving classes on an array works, but I don't know how to do that for many arrays
cls1 = (arr==0)
cls2 = (arr==1)
cls3 = (arr==2)

#I tried something like that but it doesn't work.

for s in class:
    for k in arr:
        cls = s == arr
        print(cls)
```

Comment: Store them in a dictionary `d = {}`
`for c in np.unique(arr):
    d['cls{}'.format(int(c))] = arr==c`